# react jest mock useNavigate()

Tags: jestjs, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I am trying to mock the `useNavigate` hook using Jest. I was able to do it at the top level of my test suit (I also have a custom render with `BrowserRouter` as a wrapper)

```
const mockedUsedNavigate = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...(jest.requireActual('react-router-dom') as any),
  useNavigate: () => mockedUsedNavigate,
}));

...

expect(mockedUsedNavigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith('myurl/user-1');
```

My issue is that I want to have this mock available inside the `__mocks__` directory so I can use it in other tests as well instead if having to write it again and again. I wasn't able to do it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able create a `src.setupTests.js` file in your project and declare the mock there.

See [Initializing Test Environment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#initializing-test-environment)

src/setupTests.js

```
export const navigateMock = jest.fn(); // <-- exported for test assertions

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...(jest.requireActual('react-router-dom') as any),
  useNavigate: () => navigateMock,
}));
```

You can then import the exported `navigateMock` function in test files.

Comment: Also added "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"] to my jest.config and it solved it.Thanks!